# More columns than column names

Tags: r

I am trying to read my csv on R studio (using the read.csv command), but it keeps telling me:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

I have been looking at some answers online and it seems that the problem could be that there are spaces in my column names, but I checked and I don't think there are any. Maybe it's the commas?

Here is the dataset :
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/DEKPTR
I am trying to analyze the final_score.csv (and the data_raw.csv too but it doesn't work as well)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to use `fill = TRUE`

Comment: No it didn't work :( anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The decimals are marked as `,` so, it was creating some conflict with the default `,` separated value.  Use `dec = ","` in `read.csv2`

```
df1 <- read.csv2( "final_score.csv", dec = ",")
df2 <- read.csv2( "data_raw.csv", dec = ",")
```

-output

```
> head(df1)
  country year    score score.soc score.eco score.pol
1 Austria 2014 55.65395  28.59491  20.62305  6.435980
2 Austria 2015 61.15096  35.57787  20.45061  5.122485
3 Austria 2016 59.53659  33.26864  20.01686  6.251086
4 Austria 2017 52.76985  27.92508  19.93385  4.910919
5 Austria 2018 51.85166  25.93067  20.05398  5.867006
6 Austria 2019 48.84624  23.24436  20.08117  5.520714
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   168 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ country  : chr  "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" "Austria" ...
 $ year     : int  2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2014 2015 2016 2017 ...
 $ score    : num  55.7 61.2 59.5 52.8 51.9 ...
 $ score.soc: num  28.6 35.6 33.3 27.9 25.9 ...
 $ score.eco: num  20.6 20.5 20 19.9 20.1 ...
 $ score.pol: num  6.44 5.12 6.25 4.91 5.87 ...
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   168 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ country     : chr  "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
 $ year        : int  2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2014 2015 2016 2017 ...
 $ future      : num  32.5 42.5 43.5 41.5 41 36.5 25 26 28.5 29 ...
 $ future.eu   : num  40 52 47.5 39.5 37 34.5 35.5 38.5 43.5 37.5 ...
 $ identity    : num  36.5 46 43 40.5 41.5 36 31.5 31.5 27 29.5 ...
 $ citizen     : num  24.5 31.5 32 24 23 23.5 29.5 28 29 22 ...
 $ image       : num  35 38.5 36 29 23.5 19.5 22.5 22 29 23 ...
 $ migration   : num  37 41 32 30.5 28 26.5 47 45.5 40 36 ...
 $ trust       : num  -3 3.5 5 1 2.5 0.5 -11 -10.5 -16 -11.5 ...
 $ euro        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ trade.eu    : num  81.1 80.9 80.1 83.9 85.4 ...
 $ rating      : num  1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ niip        : num  3.39 2.21 4.1 2.84 3.69 ...
 $ budget      : num  -0.372 -0.247 -0.271 -0.252 -0.349 ...
 $ polconiii   : num  0.424 0.424 0.424 0.408 0.408 ...
 $ parties     : num  26.6 26.6 26.6 27.9 27.9 ...
 $ Council     : int  8 4 9 3 3 7 4 4 1 1 ...
 $ EP          : num  16.9 12.3 14.5 10.9 17.6 ...
 $ referendums : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ majoritarian: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked after this command : 
df1 <- read.csv2( "final_score.csv", dec = ",")

What should I do with the second block of command? What is it for exactly?

Comment: @euroscepticismpdr it is just to show that the code is working for me. i.e .`str` gives the structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final_score <- read_delim("your path/final_score.csv", 
                          delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

final_score
```

```
   country  year   score score.soc score.eco score.pol
   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Austria  2014 5.57e14   2.86e14   2.06e14   6.44e14
 2 Austria  2015 6.12e14   3.56e14   2.05e13   5.12e13
 3 Austria  2016 5.95e14   3.33e14   2.00e13   6.25e14
 4 Austria  2017 5.28e13   2.79e14   1.99e14   4.91e14
 5 Austria  2018 5.19e14   2.59e14   2.01e14   5.87e14
 6 Austria  2019 4.88e13   2.32e14   2.01e14   5.52e14
 7 Belgium  2014 4.56e14   2.43e14   1.97e13   1.64e13
 8 Belgium  2015 4.60e14   2.45e14   1.97e14   1.80e14
 9 Belgium  2016 4.70e14   2.57e14   1.98e14   1.54e14
10 Belgium  2017 4.31e14   2.26e14   1.92e14   1.22e14
# … with 158 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```